# CSS | Can't fit image into main content

Tags: html, css

I wanted to make a 15% height header and footer, and for the rest height should be main (with image). But unfortunately, the image is going too big and I don't know how to resize it to 100% width (of `#all div`) and 70% (of `#all div`).

Would appreciate any help.

The [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsgET.jpg) as how it looks now.

```
html,
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#all {
    position:relative;
    width: 60%;
    height:100%;
    margin: auto;
}

header#main-header{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background:#ff0;
    height: 15%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
}

#main {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15%;
    height: 30%;
}

footer{
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:15%;   /* Height of the footer */
    background:#6cf;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using a percentage to specify height for header and footer elements, in fact, you shouldn't need to specify height at all. Just use margin/padding on the content within the header and footer to set the height.

Comment: Please share your HTML as well, so that we can answer the question.

Comment: Added php file (WordPress)

Comment: That won't help, we need the HTML that is generated by the PHP file to give you exact instruction.

Comment: PHP is no use to us. And why so much absolute positioning...that's a very poor layout method.?

Answer (score 0):

try to use `#main img {display:block; width:100% }` 
Also, I recommend you to use class instead id.